# Get total queries executed in a request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For each request/response I want to print the total number of SQL queries executed for that page request.  Is there an easy way to do this in Rails 2.x or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great gem which gives you plenty of information in all your pages, have a look at:

https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug

Answer (score 3):

Rack Bug is outdated for Rails 3.

This project is forked and continued development and looks quite good:

https://github.com/LRDesign/logical-insight

Answer (score 1):

You can use newrelic_rpm (free for local development use) to get a lot of great info.  See how many queries were run, what the actual queries were, total execution time, and even do an EXPLAIN in-line.